# Get opened Forms-Windows in WPF-Application

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to get all opened windows (WPF) and forms (WF) of my Mixed-application.
There is a method called `Application.Current.Windows` ... but its only returning the WPF Windows.

Note: The Windows Forms are stored in an other project (DLL) in the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access Windows Forms' open forms via the [`System.Windows.Forms.Application.OpenForms` static property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.openforms.aspx). The property is contained in the `System.Windows.Forms.dll` assembly, so you will need a reference to it.

(IIRC, this property only returns the forms that were created on the current thread; therefore, if you have two separate UI threads (one for Windows Forms, one for WPF), I believe you need to call the property on Windows Forms' UI thread.)

Answer (score 0):

Check this msdn 
Hope you find what your looking for.
it also has example.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.applicationservices.windowsformsapplicationbase.openforms%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: This is rather VB.NET specific, and this question is tagged C#. Even if it can be made to work in a C# application, it's more work than strictly required: You will have to somehow get a reference to a `WindowsFormsApplicationBase` object before you can access its `OpenForms` property. But there is a similar static property that doesn't rely on `WindowsFormsApplicationBase` at all; see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

For this you have to use

```
                foreach (Window win in System.Windows.Application.Current.Windows)
    {
       win..title;
    }
```